# HTML TO TXT FILE through php

Tags: php

I need to convert the HTML to txt output.like the below example,through php ,is it possible or not?

Ex:

HTML format:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Srinivasan-1</td>
        <td>welcome-1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>Srinivasan-2</td>
         <td>welcome-2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Need this type of out-put in txt format

```
Srinivasan-1      welcome-1  Test -1   
Srinivasan-2      welcome-2  Test -2
```

Comment: Yes you can use `strip_tags()` function http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Hey dude,

  I tried strip_tags(),but it will remove all tags,I need html alignment also.. example: "tr" "td" alignment like that

Comment: @Srinivasan Is that not what you want? You said you wanted to convert the HTML to text. If you want that text to have the HTML alignment, then don't remove the HTML from it, simple as that. On the other hand, I posted an answer, it removes all of the HTML BUT it also uses whitespace to keep the alignment, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm... is the PHP strip_tags function not adequate for some reason?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

You could replace each closing td and tr  with a tab and a CRLF respectively using str_replace to get the output layout you appear to be seeking.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
  <?php
    $ones= "<table><tr><td>Srinivasan-1</td><td>welcome-1</td></tr><tr><td>Srinivasan-2</td><td>welcome-2</td></tr></table>";

    $ones= strip_tags($ones);

    $file = fopen("test.txt","w");

    fwrite($file,$ones);

    fclose($file);
    ?>
```

It wont output as you wish anyway. But its the basic method of writing in to file I hope.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text to stay formatted like it is in the table, then the solution is going to be pretty complicated. With built-in PHP functions you won't be able to preserve the even spacing between the columns because it will no longer be a table, just text.

What you can do is use the [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function to get rid of the HTML. It might be desirable to place tab-characters between the columns to make it look as if it is still a table. Here is a function I whipped up:

```
<?php
    function StripHtmlFromTable($html_in)
    {
        $html_in = str_replace("</td>", "\t", $html_in); // Space the columns.
        $html_in = str_replace("</tr>", "\n", $html_in); // Put each row on a new line.
        $text_out = strip_tags($html_in);

        return $text_out;
    }
?>
```

I tested the script on my computer, here is an image of the output:

[image: The function at work, I believe this is what you want it to do?]

I had to put the output inside of `<pre>` tags so you could see how the function uses whitespace to format the text. The output looks exactly like what your example output looks like, I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi dude,

   I have checked your suggestion, I need this type of function,but how could I align for separate "td" like <td align="right">

Comment: @Srinivasan I cannot think of any way to do that, that would be a very complicated task, it would probably require regular expressions. If you want the text to behave like it is in a table, then keep it in the table. Because, since the columns are separated by actual whitespace, it would require calculations to determine how much  whitespace to put where based on how long the content of the cell is. Why do you need to strip the HTML from this?

Comment: Miller,

   Because I need to print this form in dot matrix printer,So that's why am trying this task

Comment: Oh. Well, I wouldn't know where to even start with the right-side alignment, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set of regular expressions and replace them with line breaks and tabs:

```
<?php
$raw = '<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Srinivasan-1</td>
        <td>welcome-1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>Srinivasan-2</td>
         <td>welcome-2</td>
    </tr>
</table>';
    $patterns = array(
        '/[\n\t]/si', /* remove existing whitespace and linebreaks */
        '/<tr.*?>/s', /* beginning of a row (new line) */
        '/<td.*?>([^<]+)<\/td>/s' /* all cells*/
    );
    $replaces = array(
        "", /* remove whitespace */
        "\n", /* add a new line for each tr */
        "\t$1" /* add a indent and the content of each cell */
    );
    // run the preg replace and strip all other tags
    $text = strip_tags(preg_replace($patterns,$replaces,$raw));
    echo $text;
?>
```